# how to parse bbcode [youtube]id[/youtube] in php

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I want to replace bbcode

I want to convert it to an iframe

This is what I have so far, but it doesnt work

```
  echo preg_replace('#\[yt\](.*)\[/yt\]#i', return '<iframe width="350" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$found[1].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

});
```

what Im doing wrong?

Comment: what is your `$test` variable's value?

Comment: it was just a mistake

Comment: The code you've posted is full of syntax errors. You can't just have a return statement in the middle of a function call, you've got some mismatched brackets + braces, and you're not passing in the right number of arguments. It looks like you've somehow combined examples of `preg_replace` and `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: "it doesn't work" - What happens? Regex problem? Iframe loading problem? Error messages? ...Syntax errors as @iainn mentions.

Answer (score 0):

You've managed to misinterpret the php documentation and hybridized the syntax of `preg_replace()` with `preg_replace_callback()`.  No function calls are needed to conduct the `preg_` replacement, so `preg_replace()` will do.

You can access the first capture group in the replacement string with `$1`.

Lazy character matching `*?` in the pattern will be vital if a single line of text may have multiple `[yt]...[/yt]` bbcode expressions.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DkW6N))

```
$bbcode = 'Watch this: [yt]mcbhkawik3i[/yt]!';

echo preg_replace(
    '#\[yt](.*?)\[/yt]#i',
    '<iframe width="350" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    $bbcode
);
```

Output:

```
Watch this: <iframe width="350" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mcbhkawik3i" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>!
```